# How to download a file behind a dynamic link?

Tags: java, download

I'm trying to download files with java. It works great with direct link but when it's a link from rapidshare or something else who use dynamic links, it doesn't work.

Here is my current method:

```
 URL url = new URL(link);
 ReadableByteChannel rbc = Channels.newChannel(url.openStream());
 File f =new File(Const.downloaded+filename);
 if(!f.exists()) f.createNewFile();

 FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(Const.downloaded+filename);
 fos.getChannel().transferFrom(rbc, 0, 1 << 24);
 return 0;
```

In fact it downloads a web page with a redirection.

How can I download the file directly if it's a direct link ? Thanks.

Comment: More details, please.  You have to show what happens, what kind of error you get, stack trace, etc.  Please read the [faq] and [ask]

Comment: In fact it downloads a web page with a redirection.

Comment: Looks more like uploading to me. Are you sure you don't want FileInputStream? Maybe you need to explain more what you're trying to do.

Comment: It sounds like your question is really "how to follow redirected pages in Java".

Comment: @Maerics: no because every links aren't redirected. Direct links works great.
Perry: I open a connections to link with Channels and then I redirect the output of Channel to a file (downloaded/filename where filename is randomly generated.

Comment: Ok, your question is "how do I detect a redirection and follow it when there is one".

Answer (score 0):

Please try using

```
URL url = new URL(link);
HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
ReadableByteChannel rbc = Channels.newChannel(conn.getInputStream());
```